# Ansible VSCode Extention containing module snippsets

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible

I used to use Microsoft extension for Ansible in VSCode containing module snippsets. Do you know any alternatives? Extention containing module autocompletion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft extension was unmaintained for years and I doubt those module were still following current coding standards required by Ansible.

Still, this seems like a good feature request to propose on https://github.com/ansible-community/vscode-ansible/discussions